# Indexing by Time Enter Data by Adjusting the Year

Tags: python, datetime, google-colaboratory, stockquotes

I'm studying python where the confusion is to make it by year,
I really ask for help,
I have stock data like this (data1) data from yfinance

```
data1 = yf.download(ticker,'2000-01-01','2021-01-01')
```

with the contents of the (data1)

```
Index(['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Adj Close', 'Volume'], dtype='object')
```

.

```
    Date    Open    High    Low Close*  Adj Close** Volume
04/01/2011 15:00:00 4,330.00    4,390.00    4,300.00    4,390.00    4,390.00    186,370,900
05/01/2011 15:00:00 4,260.00    4,290.00    4,210.00    4,280.00    4,280.00    128,905,400
06/01/2011 15:00:00 4,280.00    4,300.00    4,160.00    4,200.00    4,200.00    116,634,000
07/01/2012 15:00:00 4,300.00    4,300.00    4,240.00    4,270.00    4,270.00    97,239,100
08/01/2012 15:00:00 4,150.00    4,320.00    4,150.00    4,310.00    4,310.00    96,568,200
11/01/2012 15:00:00 4,150.00    4,180.00    3,950.00    4,160.00    4,160.00    170,156,900
12/01/2013 15:00:00 4,240.00    4,280.00    4,120.00    4,130.00    4,130.00    171,484,000
13/01/2013 15:00:00 4,330.00    4,340.00    4,210.00    4,210.00    4,210.00    218,968,900
14/01/2013 15:00:00 4,270.00    4,300.00    4,270.00    4,280.00    4,280.00    207,410,700
15/01/2020 15:00:00 4,360.00    4,360.00    4,310.00    4,330.00    4,330.00    141,727,100
19/01/2020 15:00:00 4,340.00    4,350.00    4,300.00    4,320.00    4,320.00    130,044,800
```

with annual data like this (data2)

```
data2 = {'eps': ['100','231', '200', '167']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data2, index = [ '2017', '2018', '2019', '2020'])
```

with the contents of the (data2)

```
Year    EPS
2017    100
2018    231
2019    200
2020    167
```

**with the end result like this,**

then nailed down the calculation of the division based on the eps year which is the same as the date on data1 with the calculation on P / EPS *(P = Adj Close ** / EPS)*

```
   Date Open    High    Low Close*  Adj Close** Volume  Eps P / EPS
04/01/2017  4,330.00    4,390.00    4,300.00    4,390.00    4,390.01    186,370,900 100 43,9
05/01/2017  4,260.00    4,290.00    4,210.00    4,280.00    4,280.01    128,905,400 100 42,8
06/01/2017  4,280.00    4,300.00    4,160.00    4,200.00    4,200.01    116,634,000 100 42,0
07/01/2018  4,300.00    4,300.00    4,240.00    4,270.00    4,270.01    97,239,100  231 18,5
08/01/2018  4,150.00    4,320.00    4,150.00    4,310.00    4,310.01    96,568,200  231 18,7
11/01/2019  4,150.00    4,180.00    3,950.00    4,160.00    4,160.01    170,156,900 200 20,8
12/01/2019  4,240.00    4,280.00    4,120.00    4,130.00    4,130.01    171,484,000 200 20,7
13/01/2019  4,330.00    4,340.00    4,210.00    4,210.00    4,210.01    218,968,900 200 21,1
14/01/2020  4,270.00    4,300.00    4,270.00    4,280.00    4,280.01    207,410,700 167 25,6
15/01/2020  4,360.00    4,360.00    4,310.00    4,330.00    4,330.01    141,727,100 167 25,9
19/01/2020  4,340.00    4,350.00    4,300.00    4,320.00    4,320.01    130,044,800 167 25,9
```

what code should I enter in python

I really appreciate your friends who help me in the my learning process, thank you